# How to change the text selection order of flex items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, textselection

The context: I have two versions of a single text, one in English and the other is a translation. It's my wish to display both side-by-side in two columns. However, as with every translation, some paragraphs are smaller or larger than the original text, and I want them to align, that is, to keep the first sentence of a paragraph aligned in both original and translation text:

```
En Paragraph         Translated Paragraph

Large en paragraph   Shorter translation
with 3               with 2 lines
lines

Both are aligned     At the top of the
Like this.           paragraph
```

However, due to the way the HTML page was constructed, I interlace the original and translated text in alternating paragraphs:

```css
.container {
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.container > p {
  flex-basis:50%;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>Large en paragraph with 3 lines (English)</p>
    <p>Shorter translation with 2 lines (Translation)</p>
    <p>Both are aligned Like this. (English)</p>
    <p>At the top of the paragraph (Translation)</p>
</div>
```

So I used `flex box` in a container and set the paragraphs to `flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 50%` to force two columns.

However, when I try to select the text to copy it from the rendered page, the cursor selects the two columns (following the structure). What I want is for the user to be able to select just either the English text or the translated text.

How could I do so?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't alternate the translation, put all the english then all the non-english. You can then rely on CSS grid instead of flexbox to create your layout:

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  width:300px;
  grid-auto-columns:1fr;
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
}

.container > * {
  grid-column:1;
}
.container > .tr {
  grid-column:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Large en paragraph with 3 lines (English)</p>
  <p>Both are aligned Like this. (English)</p>
  <p class="tr">Shorter translation with 2 lines (Translation)</p>
  <p class="tr">At the top of the paragraph (Translation)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem with the text selection, but the translation software I use generates the paragraphs interlaced, that's why I'm trying to use it as-is, instead of having to post-process it. But this is a very elegant solution, so I'll mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting text by columns at first, and by paragraphs within each column. Vertical alignment can be done via "min-height" property.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%
}

p {
  min-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Large en paragraph with 3 lines jhgvs dfhbs idufb sudhbh bdsfuyvbs odufyo iuyb (English)</p>
    <p>Both are aligned Like this. (English)</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Shorter translation with 2 lines (Translation)</p>
    <p>At the top of the paragraph (Translation)</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I have a large paragraph, the alignment will break (see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w2f67cej/)  where I implemented your answer), and to solve it I would need to increase the min-height and every paragraph would be affected.